# Partial Upgrade from 10.4 hangs

Tags: partial-upgrade

So I've been putting off doing updates and upgrades for AGES, and plus because I don't want unity and like having the window list not grouped at the bottom and having the character palette at the top 'cause I have to write with foreign Characters quite often so it's handy but I finally went to do a partial upgrade today, as suggested by the update manager, and I've left it to do its stuff but it's been stuck on: `Unpacking replacement libc-bin ...` for over 3 hours now.

aWhat can I do to push it along, or what could be stopping it from progressing?

Answer (score 0):

You may try - if this happens with your graphical tool, to abort and retry.

If you still hang: Abort and go to a shell:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I made the experience without understanding why, that it often works that way. In theory it should be the same.

Comment: So I pressed ctr-c in the terminal below the progress bar in an attempt to abort it, to which it warned me about ending the operations and leaving the system in a broken state but I said that I didn't mind that, to abort it, but it's still there and there's no close button in the window or anything. How do I abort it? Alt-F4 does nothing, as well.

Comment: Yeah.It's a window called Distristribution Upgrade and it's got the update manager icon. Yeah, I got enough space. It said it needed 900 and something MB, after downloading it still has 1.6gb free on my home partition.

Comment: Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              26G   23G  1.6G  94% /
none                  1.5G  332K  1.5G   1% /dev
none                  1.5G  1.8M  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.5G  348K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/lock
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda6             200G  200G   69M 100% /media/Storage
/dev/sdd1             932G  896G   37G  97% /media/1TB External

Comment: While it's still there I can't run the update commands you suggested, in the terminal. I get the following: 

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the list directory

So I kind of need to stop the window. Not that it's doing anything...

Comment: Thanks. Okay, yeah, so that closed the window but couldn't run the command 'cause apparently some file was still locked so I forced poweroff and restarted and run the commands but it isn't an upgrade, mind. How can I upgrade from 10.4 to the latest version?

Comment: But you can run the `sudo apt-get update` command? And afterwards try to use the graphical tool for the release-update. Btw. I will delete some of my comments, because this is getting way too chatty.